# Align label next to select with pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place these labels next to the select dropdowns. I am aligning all these items to the right using pull-right.

With the code I have, the first label/select couple is aligned to the right, but the label is on top of the select.

The second couple does not even get aligned to the right. How could I fix this?

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group pull-right">
  <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Tipo</label>
  <select name="tipo" id="tipoProveedor" style="width: 344px" class="form-control">
    <option value="todos">Todos</option>
  </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group pull-right">
  <label for="idFamilia" class="control-label">Familia</label>
  <select name="idFamilia" id="idFamilia" style="width: 344px" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="form-group pull-rigt">` you misspelled "right"

Comment: What do you want it to look like exactly? You want everything on the left, but the label to the right of the select? Or everything on the right, and the label on the left?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks, already fixed the typo. And I'd like the label to be placed on the left, so I'd have to rows aligned to the right of the page.

Comment: I hope this will help you: http://www.bootply.com/BaZcVWR9B2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want add a `form` and use `.form-horizontal`. Then  And I assigned a `col-` class to your `label`s, used `.pull-right` on the `select` and `label`, then re-ordered those 2 elements in your HTML so they'll display in the order you want on screen.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="tipo" id="tipoProveedor" style="width: 344px" class="form-control pull-right">
    <option value="todos">Todos</option>
  </select>
        <label for="tipo" class="control-label col-sm-2 pull-right">Tipo</label>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="idFamilia" id="idFamilia" style="width: 344px" class="form-control pull-right">
    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
  </select>
        <label for="idFamilia" class="control-label col-sm-2 pull-right">Familia</label>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most layout & alignment problems can be solved using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Try

```
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
div{
  min-width: 300px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
select{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

Check this out, to see if this is how you want it to be. https://jsfiddle.net/r70xa3jz

Comment: Please explain in a few words what your code does, and how it works.